# From a cumulative series, how to get the original series?

Tags: r, cumsum

My question may sound trivial. but I couldn't find from a cumulative series, how to get the non-cumulative original series in R.

Searched related question & solution in stackoverflow but had no luck.

If I am having a series `x <- c(10, 30, 60, 100)`; this is a cumulative series. I know in R, `cumsum(c(10,20,30,40))` will give me the cumulative series. But from that generated cumulative series, how can I get my original series back?

Comment: Isn't that simply the `diff()`?, i.e. `c(x[1], diff(x))` assuming `x <- c(10,30, 60, 100)`

Comment: `c(a[1], diff(a))` to get the full original vector

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen thanks for your answer. only diff returning the (n-1) observation, not entire n. a[1] or x[1] will work but here we are hardcoding the '1'. I was thinking if this can be automated! But for this time being, I will go with your answers

Comment: @HindolGanguly: I don't think there's any issue with "hardcoding" here. We know that we want (the first element of x) + (diff(x)), `c(x[1], diff(x))` is a totally straightforward expression of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `diff`, and keeping the first value, you get the original values back, i.e.

```
x <- c(10, 30, 60, 100)
diff(x)
#[1] 20 30 40
c(x[1], diff(x))
#[1] 10 20 30 40
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also remove an element from the front and back to subtract

```
c(x[1], x[-1] - x[-length(x)]) 
#[1] 10 20 30 40
```

#### data

```
x <- c(10, 30, 60, 100)
```